# Is this another puzzle? 404 image in 404 page

Tags: bug, status-completed, 404-page

I just stumbled upon [a question that was deleted here on this meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/the-many-memes-of-ppcg). ([Link to reproduce](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/404) for users with >2k rep.)

All good, questions get deleted all the time, but I couldn't help noticing something weird:

> [image]

Actually this is funny. Image not found inside Page not found. Haha.

In case it's not funny on purpose, can this be fixed?

Comment: BTW that question was PPCG memes, not really awful but the memes were doing more harm than good. More details [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13021/41024).

Comment: Also, >2k users can go to https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/404 to reproduce the issue, which, at least for me, is reproducible.

Comment: Thanks @Erik edited to remove the awful part and added the link to repro for 2k users. As for deleting it, it's weird, I thought that people who love puzzles will also like fun, guess I was wrong.

Comment: Hm, our 404 meta page uses https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/skins/sketchymeta/img/sketchy-404.png (which doesn't exist), while other sites with the beta meta design use https://cdn.sstatic.net/sites/betameta/img/404.png.

Comment: @Dennis So...we actually have a design? But then rep requirements would explode.

Comment: I think it means that SE thinks that we're sketchy.

Comment: I suspect this means we're about to get a custom 404 image.

Comment: @Mego so like pregnancy, need to suffer 6-8 months before the baby is born? ;)

Comment: This bug is too minor to be worth fixing. :(