# Is a crossed out 4 still a 4?

Tags: support

## <s>2,646</s> 3,008 characters

<sub>[Is a crossed out 4 still a 4?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133541/65907)</sub>

---

There seems to be a running joke on Code Golf that "A crossed out 4 is still a 4".

On *[Find an Illegal String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/133486/65907)*, Step Hen posted [the following answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133541/65907).

> ## [Taxi](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Taxi),  <s>4</s>  5 bytes
>
> <sup>[crossed out 4 is still 4 :(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123438/65836)</sup>
>
> ```
> '"]'"
> ```

This post linked to [Mayube's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123438/65907) for *[User Appreciation Challenge #1: Dennis ♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123194/65907)*

> ## Braingolf, <s>4</s> 3 bytes [non-competing]
>
> [crossed out 4 is still regular 4
>   :(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123404/44998)
>
> ```
> &JP
> ```

Which linked to [Challenger5's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123403/better-hex-color-codes-for-your-internet/123404#comment302922_123404) for *[Better Hex Color Codes for Your Internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123403/65907)*

> ### CJam, <s>45</s> <s>44</s> <s>42</s> <s>40</s> 36 bytes
>
> ```
> q(\0se|_,("6* 3* 2e* )f{} _W=+ "S/=~
> ```

Which included [the following exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123403/better-hex-color-codes-for-your-internet/123404#comment302916_123404) in the comments:

> Some formatting <s>not</s> required.... `<s></s>` – SteveFest
>
> @SteveFest But [crossed out 44 is still regular 44](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82343/61384)... – Challenger5
>
> Aw! You got me! I forgot that! – SteveFest

This hyperlink chain then continues to link through a multitude of answers written by different users on different questions.

[Step Hen's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133541/65907) on *[Find an Illegal String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/133486/65907)*
→ [Mayube's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/123438/65907) on *[User Appreciation Challenge #1: Dennis ♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123194/65907)*
→ [Challenger5's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123403/better-hex-color-codes-for-your-internet/123404#comment302922_123404) on *[Better Hex Color Codes for Your Internet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123403/65907)*
→ [Fatalize's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/82343/65907) on *[Closest 7-Distinct-Prime Product](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/82342/65907)*
→ [George Gibson's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79116/65907) on *[Compute the first N digits of e](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1576/65907)*
→ [GamrCorps's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77913/65907) on *[Substitution cipher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77899/65907)*
→ [daavko's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73584/65907) on *[Swap, delete and repeat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73580/65907)*
→ [Mego's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63380/65907) on *[Implement a Truth-Machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62732/65907)*
→ [AdmBorkBork's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63755/rotate-the-anti-diagonals#comment153855_63756) on *[Rotate the anti-diagonals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63755/65907)*
→ ...And so on and so forth.

**What is the running joke with crossed out 4s? How did the joke get started? Does this chain of hyperlinks have an end?**

Comment: You cannot see the memes page (because it was deleted) but [here's a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/PyqwtVM.png).

Comment: Rationale for deleting the memes: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13022/51785

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48100/very-simple-triangles/48101#comment113015_48101) is where the link chain in question leads to, by the way.

Comment: And a screenshot of why it got started (can YOU spot the difference?) https://s14.postimg.org/f7xl6896p/crossed-four.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As linked in the comments, the memes page was [deleted by the moderator team](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13022/34718). The related meme's description can be seen in the screenshot below.

I agree with their decision to delete the meme page for the same reason that you have asked this question. Because people keep referencing it in their answers. It's more annoying than helpful, so I'm hoping that the page's deletion will allow us all to forget about it, because it's also annoying when people keep linking to the meme in their answers. We've seen it a thousand times, and it's hackneyed.

[image]

Comment: I love how in the examples the cross is actually visible lol